# add audio delay in python for Simple audio library

Tags: python, opencv, audio

I am currently trying to synchronise audio and video (video output from **OpenCV**).
I am using `simpleaudio` function to play the audio directly from original source. I want to add a slight delay in audio as audio starts earlier than the video from the **OpenCV**.

Below is my code

```
import cv2 as cv
from pydub.playback import _play_with_simpleaudio

cap = cv.VideoCapture(video_file)
first_loop = True
while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret: #ret=False means frame is read correctly
            print('\nVideo not being read correctly\n')
            #cap.release()
            break
        
        key_pressed= cv.waitKey(1) 
        # first_loop to start the audio being played
        if first_loop:
            playback= _play_with_simpleaudio(audio)
        #falsify the first loop so that audio doesn't keep playing
        first_loop=False
        #release the cap file
        cap.release()
        #stop the audio from playing
        playback.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding as much silence as you want to the beginning of your audio file.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import time

audio = AudioSegment.from_file("*your_audio_file.wav*", format="wav")

# Set delay amount here
delay = 2000  # 2 seconds

# Create silent
silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=delay)

# Concatenate 
audio_with_delay = silence + audio

# Export the audio with the delay to a temporary file
audio_with_delay.export("audio_with_delay.wav", format="wav")
```

Now you can use the second wav file as your audio file.